# Why my boolean doesnt change in function?

Tags: python

i have a noob question.
I'm trying to make a blackjack and in my "turn" function i put a variable change to False.
I have no clue why it doesnt work...
It says local variable is never used, but how's that possible if it is used in the while loop...

```
import random
p1 = []
p2 = []
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
# --------------------Game on/off
game_on = True

# -----------------Random card

def pick_card(x):
  return x.append(random.choice(cards))

# ---------------- calculate score :
  
def calculate_score(x):
  if len(x)==2 and sum(x) ==21:
    return 0
  if sum(x)>21:
    if x.count(11):
      x.remove(11)
      x.append(1)
      return sum(x)
    
  return sum(x)

# ------------------------
def turn(x):
  pick_card(x)
  if calculate_score(x) == 0:
    print("blackjack")
    game_on= False
  elif calculate_score(x) >21:
    print("You lost")
    game_on= False
  else:
    print(p1)


pick_card(p1)
pick_card(p2)
pick_card(p2)
while game_on:
  turn(p1)
  if input("continue?\n") == "y":
    game_on = True
  else:
    game_on=False
```

Comment: If a variable is set anywhere in a function it is seen as local to this function (if not explicitly declared as "global") and shadows (hides) a global variable of same name. Because this local variable is only set but never read it is seen as unused.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `game_on` variable as *global*:

```
def turn(x):
    global game_on
    pick_card(x)
    if calculate_score(x) == 0:
        print("blackjack")
        game_on = False
    elif calculate_score(x) > 21:
        print("You lost")
        game_on = False
    else:
        print(p1)
```

Also, fix your indentations.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appriciate the help. :)